# Favorite/unfavorite -missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
No route matches {:controller=>"guides", :action=>"favorite", :id=>nil, :format=>nil, :type=>"favorite"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'm trying to get a favorites list going in my application. Users should be able to favorite and unfavorite guides.

favorite action in guides controller:

```
def favorite
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
      type = params[:type]
      if type == "favorite"
        current_user.favorites << @guide
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@guide.title}'

      elsif type == "unfavorite"
        current_user.favorites.delete(@guide)
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@guide.title}'

      else
        # Type missing, nothing happens
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
      end
    end
```

favorite_guide.rb

```
class FavoriteGuide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guide
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

guide.rb

```
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_guides, source: :user
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :guides do
    member do
      put "like", to: "guides#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "guides#downvote"
    end
    put :favorite, on: :member
  end
```

Here's how I print them out in the view:

```
<%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_guide_path(@guide, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
  <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_guide_path(@guide, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
```

Comment: Where's it throwing an error?

Comment: Updated the original post. It throws the error in the view when I try to print out favorite and unfavorite links.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing

```
<%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_guide_path(@guide, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_guide_path(@guide, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_guide_path(guide, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_guide_path(guide, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
```